# Checking if mysqli_query returned any values?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code and I would like to know if `mysqli_query` returned any rows and if so return an error.

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM users");
    
if ($result == "") {
    echo "No records found";
} else {
    echo "There is at least one record in the database";
}
```

I'm having trouble if the results come back as empty. I've tried using several things and can't figure out how to get it work correctly if nothing is found.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to check if any rows were returned or not.

Answer (score 10):

use `mysqli_num_rows` like this

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "email was not found";
} else {
    echo "email was found";
}
```