# I am getting this error Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php

I am getting this error

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in E:\xampp\htdocs\word-meaning-learn\word-ajax-insert.php on line 15
> Inserted the meaning data!

What's wrong with the code on the line? > `if($row['bangla_mean'] == $bangla_mean)`

```
<?php
include "config.php";
$bangla_mean = $_POST["bangla_mean"];
$english_mean = $_POST["english_mean"];
$example_mean = $_POST["example_mean"];
$synonym_mean = $_POST["synonym_mean"];

if(isset($bangla_mean)){
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT bangla_mean FROM wordmeanings_table WHERE bangla_mean=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$bangla_mean);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if($row['bangla_mean'] == $bangla_mean){
  $response = "This Bangla meaning already exist!";
  }
 else{
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO wordmeanings_table (bangla_mean, english_mean, example_mean, synonym_mean) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$bangla_mean,$english_mean,$example_mean,$synonym_mean);
      if($stmt->execute()){
        $response = "Inserted the meaning data!";
      }
      else{
        $response = "Something went wrong!";
      }
  }
}

echo $response;
        exit;
?>
```

Comment: Get rid of `$row['bangla_mean'] == $bangla_mean`. If you get a result it is true because `WHERE bangla_mean=?`.

Comment: if `$row` is an array do you mean `$row[$bangla_mean]`

Comment: `Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null` means that the array you're trying to get data from, is not an array - but is a null instead.

Looks like your db query is not giving results.

Comment: @depperm `$row` wouldn't have `$bangla_mean` as an index, unless the value and the column have the same name.

Comment: that or you tried to access an array using null as an index or higher than the size of the array

Comment: @user3783243 its probable, I don't think using a string as index was intentional/should be the way to access an array

Comment: Can anyone tell me the exact correct code to get rid of the warning?

Comment: @NajmulHasan Check if you have a return, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996649/checking-if-mysqli-query-returned-any-values

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that `$row` variable is null, but you're trying to treat it as an array. Null is a legal returning value of `fetch_array()` method when no rows found. If row found, method returns an associative array for requested "bangla_mean" from POST.

```
if (is_array($row)) {
    $response = "This Bangla meaning already exist!";
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Or another option to check `$row` is not a null:

```
if ($row !== null) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You query is empty you try to get the result of "?", it's not logic.. try to do that instead:

```
if(isset($bangla_mean)){
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT bangla_mean FROM wordmeanings_table WHERE bangla_mean='$bangla_mean'");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$bangla_mean);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```