# How many rows I got from SQL?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to get some values from my MySQL database. I send a request and get the data back. Then I say: `$value->fetch_assoc()`. My question now is, how can I check if I got 0 Rows back or at least more than 0?

Is that right?:

```
if($row = $value->fetch_assoc() > 0){...}
```

If not, how can I check that?
And I'am forced to use `>= 0` or is just `>0` ok? - I want only to enter the if if I got more than 0 (1 or bigger) back!

Comment: You can check the number of rows with `$value->num_rows`. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php - and if you do `>= 0` you include 0, so it doesn't matter how many rows are returned, 0 or one million.

Comment: To extend on this, there's *lots* of [other alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286586/best-way-to-check-if-mysql-results-returned-in-php), but `$value->num_rows` is definitely best.

Comment: So I should use only `>0` to check if bigger 0?

Comment: That's what `> 0` means! "*Greater than zero*"!

Comment: That it **literally** what  `> 0` means... It checks that you get more than zero (at least 1) row returned from the query.

Comment: And to check if it is one I use `= 1`or `== 1`?

Comment: `=` assigns, `==` compares.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So `==` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check by using the variable num_rows of a query result:

```
if($value->num_rows > 0) {...}
```

Have a nice day