# How to perform condition when null is retrieved from the database?

Tags: php

I am retrieving the details from the database if the condition is satisfied.
But when the condition is not satisfied, empty result is retrived.
So how to have a condition if status is empty

```
$sq = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$ro = mysqli_fetch_array($sq);
$status = $ro['status'];

if ($status == 1) {
    header("location: paymentPage.php");
} elseif ($status == 0) {
    header("location:login.php");
} elseif ($status == '\0') {
    header("location:SignUp.php");
}
```

But I am not able to redirect to signup page if the status is empty.Is status=='\0' is correct to go for signup page.

Comment: I think this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't check if status is empty, you check if query returned something. I think you've disabled error reporting and don't really see that acessing `$ro['status']` fails when there are no results.

Comment: The result will be empty right if there is no record with that specified name. Then , can i directly access that if $res == ""

Comment: I don't know what `$res` is, but there are better ways of checking if the query found any results than using `== ""`. Such as [Best way to check if MySQL results returned in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286586/best-way-to-check-if-mysql-results-returned-in-php). **Warning: the linked question uses deprecated API, adapt it accordingly.**

Answer (score 0):

If your column **status** has integer type in DB then it can't have value '\0' because '\0' is a string.
Maybe you should use `is_null` function?
For example:

```
else if(is_null($status))
{
    header("location:SignUp.php"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In all case, `mysqli_fetch_array` function will return `array|null|false` types. It means that, if your connection didn't establish or data is empty, your response will return empty array or empty string|boolean item. Therefore, you can check if is exits by any case like that:

```php
if( !($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sq)))
{
  // Data doesn't exists
  header("location:SignUp.php"); 
}else{
  $status = $ro['status'];
  echo 'My other validations';
}
```

To read documentation about function look at: https://www.php.net/manual/tr/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php